# Generate JavaScript file with PHP when requested in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, request, code-generation, server

How do I Generate a JavaScript file with PHP when it is requested in an HTML program?  I want a PHP program like this that runs on the server when a certain JavaScript file is requested.  Example code:

```
<?php
    If (requested("file:///C:/server/htdocs/javascriptgenerator.php") {
        javascript-code-to-give-to-client = "function myFunction(){...";
    }
?>
```

I know that was very fake code, but that is how I write when I don't know how to do it.  I would also want this file to always be running on the server in case the file is requested.  I also want to know how to just send the file as normal.  I also want to know how to do this depending on the client.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why do you want to do that?

Comment: i don't know why you would want to do this, there's not enough context, but check out `file_put_contents()`

Comment: Well I want to do it depending on what the client is.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The easiest way is to not actually use javascriptfile.js. Instead have a new php file called javascriptgenerator.php or something with the following code in:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/javascript');

if($condition){
    echo file_get_contents('js/javascript_file_a.js');
}
```

The header() line ensures that the browser will pick up  that it's a JS file.

Using this in an HTML file is simple, just use this line of code in the `<head>` tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascriptgenerator.php"></script>
```

If you need to find out information about the client you can inspect the user agent, which you can then pass to the `get_browser()` function like this:

```
$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$browser_info = get_browser($user_agent);
```

Example get Browser Output (from [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php)):

```
Array
(
    [browser_name_regex] => ^mozilla/5\.0 (windows; .; windows nt 5\.1; .*rv:.*) gecko/.* firefox/0\.9.*$
    [browser_name_pattern] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; ?; Windows NT 5.1; *rv:*) Gecko/* Firefox/0.9*
    [parent] => Firefox 0.9
    [platform] => WinXP
    [browser] => Firefox
    [version] => 0.9
    [majorver] => 0
    [minorver] => 9
    [cssversion] => 2
    [frames] => 1
    [iframes] => 1
    [tables] => 1
    [cookies] => 1
    [backgroundsounds] =>
    [vbscript] =>
    [javascript] => 1
    [javaapplets] => 1
    [activexcontrols] =>
    [cdf] =>
    [aol] =>
    [beta] => 1
    [win16] =>
    [crawler] =>
    [stripper] =>
    [wap] =>
    [netclr] =>
)
```

Comment: How am I supposed to get the script in HTML?  How do I do it depending on the client?