# run php file with script tag

Tags: javascript, php, html

Is there any way to insert php code through `<script>`? Like `<script src="example.php">. I know that script is only for JS but I want PHP to generate JS that I can insert with script tag. Here I found a possible sollution: [Generate JavaScript file with PHP when requested in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26854950/generate-javascript-file-with-php-when-requested-in-html).
PHP file:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/javascript');


 $json = '{"title":" \\ud83c\\uddf7\\ud83c\\uddfa \\u0420\\u043e\\u0441\\u0441\\u0438\\u0439\\u0441\\u043a\\u043e\\u0435 \\u043a\\u0430\\u0437\\u0438\\u043d\\u043e #1 
\\ud83c\\uddf7\\ud83c\\uddfa ","desc":"\\u0422\\u043e\\u043b\\u044c\\u043a\\u043e 
\\u0437\\u0430\\u0440\\u0435\\u0433\\u0438\\u0441\\u0442\\u0440\\u0438\\u0440\\u0443\\u0439\\u0441\\u044f \\u0438 \\u0438\\u0433\\u0440\\u0430\\u0439 
\\u043f\\u0435\\u0440\\u0432\\u044b\\u0439 \\u0440\\u0430\\u0437 \\u0437\\u0430 \\u043d\\u0430\\u0448 
\\u0441\\u0447\\u0451\\u0442","icn":"https://1.mbvnclick1.com/ic?sid=2&data=0eikgji0Ck2EKXJkLTJfLie%2FKy%2FvWYZiVPrhxIOQsl6VkyioGiy%2B4DYdpqaaMXlM5dVPkQoRzngoPAlvQ3w1pREOxlMjuR7DQHq6Yz0oA7ZXT9CV1ut2ICfrquV9FoQ%2BjltIeJAcUnB%2BTMvTjn%2BGs1lvh5bOIUUXYa0tIJCe%2BJe2LX38OpOLAJ%2B7U1h12rvXozelMT5SGd67wzUnFI7er3gJycSu7WAH72sUTT%2FZ%2F3nJQOZBOMHY8WyX8jqel5Mo8BMNLzIXHyjpA%2BiZlgYsEg%3D%3D","img":"https://1.mbvnclick1.com/im?sid=2&data=ZQqgvmU6z8ZR4RPBdAhPWcdkbt5b%2BWp435ln18YHYo1SXskUGSiZhGwhvcXnWECjuteCzRQRWIhfYTUDd4wLcUq7jKaYn55gJUbQZr3UM6SAx2dKKXUVQVmstTsIdXma7gZ57%2B8L58uusM7pf8HpgSTreH8rjJIX%2BQEruq544CQQF%2FTNxTpCAesrBgQpkUOL76hSB%2F0Eaw3yYO0mDUDR6zKLXkDo6cxruIRrER05RSFJVtlFr3ihmDZHJQZnl%2FO6","url":"https://1.mbvnclick1.com/clpsh?sid=2&d=1&data=h3OP98W8RXI52WXh0xUpzzPCqkn%2Boc1q7OZh2tb7pLxLU4il0MNlbTTRR%2FQJ3Ryj98kKbM2eOgq%2FVtMBpmy4huEGwavyp41rQdZTT%2Fjdsu0QcYNMwUiNBH4mifSNaIzMTDYTeB9hZ8BPwGw%2F171wk2af2qmrmLi7e13XtfK%2BFpZltozDNAqS%2BDJkvH3SVKJHo8TkGjb2FQonQoXeVXqfp6jp2MYLqp%2FOFf6dOcERVM%2Ff%2FYBgEZ2E%2FpzuMZSywxPt49sveDcfOE%2F9LOjBu6%2BU1XymVQdknq%2B0MzuJAd6Eq8%2FH4q%2F%2B7dlgvivqQm30C%2FvhG%2FfGSYQPEY%2BHdzAJZ%2FStRjZmMtGhsqHbMkGENTil4bzlo8VvMW6H2yLPpVVw8Eqw86jXlndl7qPusmT4W4VUVQzMEnKgDbiJFPGy45vE%2B3QOCqafNoCq90X7U%2FLlvr9Gxdox8qAUyhAMbqJU5p0GYlMk6iJDD3GaG%2FqAZN5hzM0%3D","price":"0.0055"}'; 
$json = preg_replace('/[[:cntrl:]]/', '', $json); $json = json_decode($json, true); ?> <a href="https://airlinetravel.life/"> <div> <div> <p> <?php echo $json['title']; ?> </p> <p> 
<?php echo $json['desc']; ?> </p> <div class="iconBanner"> <img src="<?php echo $json['icn']; ?>"> </div> <div class="imgBanner"> <img src="<?php echo $json['img']; ?>"> </div> 
</div> </div> </a>
?>
```

But I have an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` because in php file I have HTML and JS finds it as an error.

I found how to do this here:[Generate JavaScript file with PHP when requested in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26854950/generate-javascript-file-with-php-when-requested-in-html). But I have error

Comment: No, it's not possible. Code in script tags is run in the browser, PHP runs on the server.

Comment: `mbvnclick1` is a malicious site. You shouldn't be trying to retrieve anything from there in the first place.

Comment: @Barmar yesterday I thought it's not possible too. But as you can see it's possible

Comment: I misread the question. I thought you wanted to run PHP in the browser, not use PHP to generate the JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When need to generate a JS script via PHP, you should think in JS way.
To add an HTML element from js you must use some functions like `document.write()`.

Your sample code changed like this:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/javascript');


 $json = '{"title":" \\ud83c\\uddf7\\ud83c\\uddfa \\u0420\\u043e\\u0441\\u0441\\u0438\\u0439\\u0441\\u043a\\u043e\\u0435 \\u043a\\u0430\\u0437\\u0438\\u043d\\u043e #1 
\\ud83c\\uddf7\\ud83c\\uddfa ","desc":"\\u0422\\u043e\\u043b\\u044c\\u043a\\u043e 
\\u0437\\u0430\\u0440\\u0435\\u0433\\u0438\\u0441\\u0442\\u0440\\u0438\\u0440\\u0443\\u0439\\u0441\\u044f \\u0438 \\u0438\\u0433\\u0440\\u0430\\u0439 
\\u043f\\u0435\\u0440\\u0432\\u044b\\u0439 \\u0440\\u0430\\u0437 \\u0437\\u0430 \\u043d\\u0430\\u0448 
\\u0441\\u0447\\u0451\\u0442","icn":"https://1.mbvnclick1.com/ic?sid=2&data=0eikgji0Ck2EKXJkLTJfLie%2FKy%2FvWYZiVPrhxIOQsl6VkyioGiy%2B4DYdpqaaMXlM5dVPkQoRzngoPAlvQ3w1pREOxlMjuR7DQHq6Yz0oA7ZXT9CV1ut2ICfrquV9FoQ%2BjltIeJAcUnB%2BTMvTjn%2BGs1lvh5bOIUUXYa0tIJCe%2BJe2LX38OpOLAJ%2B7U1h12rvXozelMT5SGd67wzUnFI7er3gJycSu7WAH72sUTT%2FZ%2F3nJQOZBOMHY8WyX8jqel5Mo8BMNLzIXHyjpA%2BiZlgYsEg%3D%3D","img":"https://1.mbvnclick1.com/im?sid=2&data=ZQqgvmU6z8ZR4RPBdAhPWcdkbt5b%2BWp435ln18YHYo1SXskUGSiZhGwhvcXnWECjuteCzRQRWIhfYTUDd4wLcUq7jKaYn55gJUbQZr3UM6SAx2dKKXUVQVmstTsIdXma7gZ57%2B8L58uusM7pf8HpgSTreH8rjJIX%2BQEruq544CQQF%2FTNxTpCAesrBgQpkUOL76hSB%2F0Eaw3yYO0mDUDR6zKLXkDo6cxruIRrER05RSFJVtlFr3ihmDZHJQZnl%2FO6","url":"https://1.mbvnclick1.com/clpsh?sid=2&d=1&data=h3OP98W8RXI52WXh0xUpzzPCqkn%2Boc1q7OZh2tb7pLxLU4il0MNlbTTRR%2FQJ3Ryj98kKbM2eOgq%2FVtMBpmy4huEGwavyp41rQdZTT%2Fjdsu0QcYNMwUiNBH4mifSNaIzMTDYTeB9hZ8BPwGw%2F171wk2af2qmrmLi7e13XtfK%2BFpZltozDNAqS%2BDJkvH3SVKJHo8TkGjb2FQonQoXeVXqfp6jp2MYLqp%2FOFf6dOcERVM%2Ff%2FYBgEZ2E%2FpzuMZSywxPt49sveDcfOE%2F9LOjBu6%2BU1XymVQdknq%2B0MzuJAd6Eq8%2FH4q%2F%2B7dlgvivqQm30C%2FvhG%2FfGSYQPEY%2BHdzAJZ%2FStRjZmMtGhsqHbMkGENTil4bzlo8VvMW6H2yLPpVVw8Eqw86jXlndl7qPusmT4W4VUVQzMEnKgDbiJFPGy45vE%2B3QOCqafNoCq90X7U%2FLlvr9Gxdox8qAUyhAMbqJU5p0GYlMk6iJDD3GaG%2FqAZN5hzM0%3D","price":"0.0055"}'; 
$json = preg_replace('/[[:cntrl:]]/', '', $json);
$json = json_decode($json, true);
?>

document.write("<a href=\"https://airlinetravel.life/\"> <div> <div> <p> <?php echo $json['title']; ?> </p> <p> <?php echo $json['desc']; ?> </p> <div class=\"iconBanner\"> <img src=\"<?php echo $json['icn']; ?>\"> </div> <div class=\"imgBanner\"> <img src=\"<?php echo $json['img']; ?>\"> </div></div> </div> </a>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are directly mixing HTML inside `php` tags. You can close the `php` tag before using HTML tags.

```
<?php
  header('Content-Type: text/javascript');

  $json = '{"title":" \\ud83c\\uddf7\\ud83c\\uddfa \\u0420\\u043e\\u0441\\u0441\\u0438\\u0439\\u0441\\u043a\\u043e\\u0435 \\u043a\\u0430\\u0437\\u0438\\u043d\\u043e #1 
\\ud83c\\uddf7\\ud83c\\uddfa ","desc":"\\u0422\\u043e\\u043b\\u044c\\u043a\\u043e 
\\u0437\\u0430\\u0440\\u0435\\u0433\\u0438\\u0441\\u0442\\u0440\\u0438\\u0440\\u0443\\u0439\\u0441\\u044f \\u0438 \\u0438\\u0433\\u0440\\u0430\\u0439 
\\u043f\\u0435\\u0440\\u0432\\u044b\\u0439 \\u0440\\u0430\\u0437 \\u0437\\u0430 \\u043d\\u0430\\u0448 
\\u0441\\u0447\\u0451\\u0442","icn":"https://1.mbvnclick1.com/ic?sid=2&data=0eikgji0Ck2EKXJkLTJfLie%2FKy%2FvWYZiVPrhxIOQsl6VkyioGiy%2B4DYdpqaaMXlM5dVPkQoRzngoPAlvQ3w1pREOxlMjuR7DQHq6Yz0oA7ZXT9CV1ut2ICfrquV9FoQ%2BjltIeJAcUnB%2BTMvTjn%2BGs1lvh5bOIUUXYa0tIJCe%2BJe2LX38OpOLAJ%2B7U1h12rvXozelMT5SGd67wzUnFI7er3gJycSu7WAH72sUTT%2FZ%2F3nJQOZBOMHY8WyX8jqel5Mo8BMNLzIXHyjpA%2BiZlgYsEg%3D%3D","img":"https://1.mbvnclick1.com/im?sid=2&data=ZQqgvmU6z8ZR4RPBdAhPWcdkbt5b%2BWp435ln18YHYo1SXskUGSiZhGwhvcXnWECjuteCzRQRWIhfYTUDd4wLcUq7jKaYn55gJUbQZr3UM6SAx2dKKXUVQVmstTsIdXma7gZ57%2B8L58uusM7pf8HpgSTreH8rjJIX%2BQEruq544CQQF%2FTNxTpCAesrBgQpkUOL76hSB%2F0Eaw3yYO0mDUDR6zKLXkDo6cxruIRrER05RSFJVtlFr3ihmDZHJQZnl%2FO6","url":"https://1.mbvnclick1.com/clpsh?sid=2&d=1&data=h3OP98W8RXI52WXh0xUpzzPCqkn%2Boc1q7OZh2tb7pLxLU4il0MNlbTTRR%2FQJ3Ryj98kKbM2eOgq%2FVtMBpmy4huEGwavyp41rQdZTT%2Fjdsu0QcYNMwUiNBH4mifSNaIzMTDYTeB9hZ8BPwGw%2F171wk2af2qmrmLi7e13XtfK%2BFpZltozDNAqS%2BDJkvH3SVKJHo8TkGjb2FQonQoXeVXqfp6jp2MYLqp%2FOFf6dOcERVM%2Ff%2FYBgEZ2E%2FpzuMZSywxPt49sveDcfOE%2F9LOjBu6%2BU1XymVQdknq%2B0MzuJAd6Eq8%2FH4q%2F%2B7dlgvivqQm30C%2FvhG%2FfGSYQPEY%2BHdzAJZ%2FStRjZmMtGhsqHbMkGENTil4bzlo8VvMW6H2yLPpVVw8Eqw86jXlndl7qPusmT4W4VUVQzMEnKgDbiJFPGy45vE%2B3QOCqafNoCq90X7U%2FLlvr9Gxdox8qAUyhAMbqJU5p0GYlMk6iJDD3GaG%2FqAZN5hzM0%3D","price":"0.0055"}'; 

  $json = preg_replace('/[[:cntrl:]]/', '', $json); $json = json_decode($json, true);
?>

document.write(`<a href="https://airlinetravel.life/">
  <div>
    <div>
      <p><?php echo $json['title']; ?></p>
      <p><?php echo $json['desc']; ?></p>
      <div class="iconBanner">
        <img src="<?php echo $json['icn']; ?>">
      </div>
      <div class="imgBanner">
        <img src="<?php echo $json['img']; ?>">
      </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
</a>`);
```